# Particular solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following Cauchy- Euler equation by the method of variation parameters.
\begin{equation}
(x^2D^2+2xD-12)y=x^2\log(x).
\end{equation}
The complementary solution of associated homogeneous equation is
\begin{equation}
y_c(x)=c_1x^{-4}+c_2x^3.
\end{equation}
and the Wronskian of two solutions is  $W(y_1, y_2)(x)=7x^{-2}.$
By the method of variation of parameters, I got the particular solution as
\begin{equation}
y_p(x)=\frac{1}{64} x^4 (-9 + 8 \log(x)).
\end{equation}
Question: While verifying the particular solution by back substitution I am  getting righthand side function as $x^4\log(x)$ instead of $x^2\log(x)$. Why?

Note: By the operator method I got the particular solution as
\begin{equation}
y_p(x)=-\frac{x^2}{36}\left(6\log(x)+5\right).
\end{equation}

Comment: Divide both sides of the ODE by $x^2$ before carrying out variation of parameters. The coefficient on the second derivative should be $1$ before you carry out the method.

Comment: thank you , i got  my question clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint
$$(x^2D^2+2xD-12)y=x^2\log(x).$$
$$\left(D^2+\dfrac 2x D-\dfrac {12}{x^2}\right)y=\log x$$
Now apply the methof od variaion of parameters. Note that $f=\log x$ and not $x^2 \log x$ you should get the correct answer.